# The fileDownloaded cookie is sent over a secure connection but does not have the "secure" attribute set

Tags: security, tomcat, cookies

A security scan performed on my tomcat install is reporting this problem:

The fileDownloaded cookie is sent over a secure connection but does not have the "secure" attribute set. The "secure" attribute tells the browser to only transmit cookies over connections secured with SSL. This protects the values from being inadverntly sent over unencrypted HTTP connections.

I've gone through and set the secure="true" in server.xml and set useHttpOnly="true" in context.xml

This fixed the issue on all the actual pages they now all show Set Cookie secure in the header

But this fileDownlaoded cookie is the last lingering bit reporting a problem.

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find any reference to anyone else having this problem.

I'm starting to wonder if this is actually a configuration issue with the iPlanet Web Server and not the Tomcat App Server

Request

```
GET ------ HTTP/1.1
Host: www
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Cookie: JSESSIONID=*****
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: https://********dashboard.page
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: none
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2015 05:08:05 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Location:
Proxy-agent: Oracle-iPlanet-Web-Server/7.0
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="table_export.xls"
Set-cookie: fileDownloaded=true;Version=1
Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Via: 1.1 *******
Content-Length: 4608
```

Comment: Unless that cookie is sensitive, there is no advantage in making it TLS/SSL only. The only possible information an attacker could glean is presumably whether the user has downloaded a file. It is up to your judgement whether knowledge of that parameter constitutes a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat never sets a cookie called `fileDownloaded`: this is an application issue.

If you want your cookies to have the "secure" flag set, then you need to make sure that you set it yourself:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("fileDownloaded", "true");
cookie.setVersion(1);
cookie.setSecure(true);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

You might want to check that the current connection is *actually secure* before setting that flag.

Comment: Thanks, The servlet uses a javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie.NewCookie() for the file download. The developer thinks we could use the NewCookie(Cookie cookie, String comment, int maxAge, Date expiry, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly) but that needs version 3 while they are using 2.5

Comment: I just wanted to come back and say thanks. We implemented a code fix and while not exactly the way you suggested your answer pointed the developer in the right direction so, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For our specific implementation we needed to use:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie.NewCookie() 
NewCookie(Cookie cookie, String comment, int maxAge, Date expiry, boolean secure, boolean httpOnly)
```